NullPointerException when searching in my SOAP web service
I'm developing a SOAP web service in Java using JAX-WS, and I'm encountering a 'NullPointerException' when trying to search for films that have been previously added to the service. The issue seems to occur specifically within my 'rechercherFilms' method, which is responsible for finding films based on a keyword ('motcle')
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
@WebService(name = "CinemaService")
public class CinemaService {

    private Map<Integer, Film> films = new HashMap<>();
    private int idFilm = 1;

    @WebMethod
    public Film ajouterFilms(@WebParam(name="titre") String titre,
                             @WebParam(name="genre") String genre,
                             @WebParam(targetNamespace="duree") int duree,
                             @WebParam(targetNamespace="places") int nbrPlace) {
        Film film = new Film();
        film.setId(idFilm++);
        film.setTitre(titre);
        film.setGenre(genre);
        film.setDuree(duree);
        film.setNbrPlace(nbrPlace);
        films.put(film.getId(), film);
        return film;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public List<Film> rechercherFilms(@WebParam(name="motcle") String motCle) {
        List<Film> filmsTrouves = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Film film : films.values()) {
            if (film.getTitre() != null && film.getGenre() != null) {
                if (film.getTitre().toLowerCase().contains(motCle.toLowerCase()) ||
                    film.getGenre().toLowerCase().contains(motCle.toLowerCase())) {
                    filmsTrouves.add(film);
                }
            }
        }
        return filmsTrouves;
    }
}


When I call the 'rechercherFilms' method with a valid 'motcle' (keyword), I receive the following SOAP fault message:
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>


Can someone please help me understand why this exception is happening and how I can modify my code to handle it correctly? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Does any error trace get printed in the log file?

You should run your service in a debugger and check what exactly is null and in what circumstances.
